# Can you loop a Perl 6 block that's in a variable?

Tags: raku, control-structure

I keep wanting to do something like this:

```
my $block := {
    state $n = 0;
    say $n++;
    last if $n > 3;
    };

loop $block;
```

Or even:

```
$block.loop;
```

I'm not expecting that this is possible but it would sure be cool if it was.

How would I find out where a particular routine comes from?

```
$ perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> &loop.^name
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Undeclared routine:
    loop used at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using what is already in Perl 6, you can use [`Seq.from-loop`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/from-loop) in sink context.
(Note that the REPL doesn't put the last statement on a line into sink context)

```perl6
my $block := {
    state $n = 0;
    say $n++;
    last if $n > 3;
}

Seq.from-loop: $block;
```

```perl6
Seq.from-loop: {say $++}, {$++ <= 3};
```

Comment: Oh very nice. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I feel this is entering an implementation specific grey area.  Not sure you would want to put this in a book.

Answer (score 5):

Making `$block.loop` work, is rather easy and could live in module land:

```
use MONKEY;
augment class Block {
    method loop($self:) {
        Nil while $self()
    }
}
my $a = { print "a" };
$a.loop  # aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (with apologies to Knorkator)
```

Making `loop $block` work would be rather more involved, as this would involve changes to the action handling of the Perl 6 grammar.